# unexpected frame appears onto another frame after an event

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I'm using a character application. In the first page, there is a frame `f-selection` where the search fields are entered. When I search for something and open some other frames in that search, then I press F10 which is for opening another frame, the new frame opens but `f-selection` also appears on it. I'm suspecting this code makes it pop up again:

```
else assign ll-lgst-key1:SENSITIVE in frame f-selection = TRUE
            ll-lgst-key2:SENSITIVE in frame f-selection = FALSE
```

because when I comment these lines, the frame doesn't pop up. But then I can't use these fields at the first frame where I should, too. I don't know why this code is called again; but is there anything else I can do to fix this issue? I tried to write `hide frame f-selection` everywhere possible but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

That snippet of code is making "key1" of your frame sensitive.  In order to be sensitive it needs to pop up...

So the issue is why is that block of code executing?  You say "I don't know why this code is called again".  Neither will anyone else because you have shared such a tiny little bit of the overall code.  Apparently the flow of control is taking you through that block so you should work on understanding why that is.  You might try using the debugger to step through the code execution or you could insert some old fashioned MESSAGE statements to get to the bottom of it.

If you want to kludge around the problem you could wrap that bit of code in conditional logic.  Define and set a variable that determines the desired state of the f-selection frame and use that to control the sensitivity logic:

```
define variable f-shouldBeVisible as logical no-undo.

if .... then
  f-shouldBeVisible = yes.
 else
  f-shouldBeVisible = no.

...

 else
  do:
    if f-shouldBeVisible then
      assign ll-lgst-key1:SENSITIVE in frame f-selection = TRUE
             ll-lgst-key2:SENSITIVE in frame f-selection = FALSE
      .
  end.
```

Of course that looks kind of silly -- but it is just an example with grossly over-simplified logic.

OTOH if you know enough to set the variable you ought to be able to figure out why the ELSE branch is executing.  But maybe it is a useful first step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I shared a tiny code block because It's a really big project (from work) and all of the files are connected, also there are so many includes and other types of files.. Also we are using Ultra edit to develop and edit the code. This part of the code is also a a part of string variable that I'm sending to a file..I thought of adding if-else but the codes are huge so I can't be sure about what am I gonna affect or where exactly to add it.. Thanks anyways!